# Couldn't add foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to add a foreign key using MySQL Workbench. I created a new table and clicked on foreign keys tab and it shows the columns. But the checkbox is not activated. The column is INT data type on both tables. Could you please suggest what could be wrong? I appreciate any help.

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table1` (
  `t_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `t_name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`t_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `newid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `t_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`newid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: is the column a primary key on the table being referenced?  Showing us the actual schema would be helpful.

Comment: What storage engine are you using for the tables? Note that InnoDB is the *only* MySQL storage engine that supports foreign-key constraints. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both columns are of type `INT`, one of them is `unsigned` as well. They must both be `unsigned` for a foreign key to be established.

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table1` (
  `t_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `t_name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`t_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `newid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `t_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  --------------^^^^^^^^^^
  -- Must be unsigned...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`newid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key needs to be of the same type as the referenced column.  You would need to make the t_id unsigned on the table with the foreign key.